# TypeError: string argument without an encoding in 3.4 but not in 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have written a class to represent LZMA compressed data with a base64 encoded string:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from lzma import LZMADecompressor


class B64LZMA(str):
    """A string of base64 encoded, LZMA compressed data."""

    def __bytes__(self):
        """Returns the decompressed data."""
        return LZMADecompressor().decompress(b64decode(self.encode()))

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string decoded from __bytes__."""
        return bytes(self).decode()


TEST_STR = B64LZMA('/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L+WjAQALSGVsbG8gd29ybGQuAGt+oFiSvoAYAAEkDKYY2NgftvN9AQAAAAAEWVo=')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(TEST_STR)
```

While this works perfectly in python 3.6 on ArchLinux, I get the following error on python 3.4 on Debian 8:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(TEST_STR)
  File "./test.py", line 16, in __str__
    return bytes(self).decode()
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Why is there this discrepancy in behaviour between python 3.4 and python 3.6 and how can I get the above class to work in python 3.4 as well?

**Update**

Script to verify:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from base64 import b64decode
from lzma import LZMADecompressor
from sys import version


class B64LZMA(str):
    """A string of base64 encoded, LZMA compressed data."""

    def __bytes__(self):
        """Returns the decompressed data."""
        return LZMADecompressor().decompress(b64decode(self.encode()))

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string decoded from __bytes__."""
        return bytes(self).decode()


TEST_STR = B64LZMA('/Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L+WjAQALSGVsbG8gd29ybGQuAGt+oFiSvoAYAAEkDKYY2NgftvN9AQAAAAAEWVo=')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(version)
    print(TEST_STR)
```

SHA-256 sum: 64513a7508b20dda5cc26c37fa4dc8f516369937569833bb0957c10ea887ae00

Output with python 3.4 on Debian 8:

```
$ ./test.py 
3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(TEST_STR)
  File "./test.py", line 17, in __str__
    return bytes(self).decode()
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Output with python 3.6 on ArchLinux:

```
$ ./test.py 
3.6.4 (default, Dec 23 2017, 19:07:07) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20171128]
Hello world.
```

Comment: It's the `bytes` constructor that fails. `bytes("")` fails with the same error, on *Python34* **and** *Python36*, but works on *Python27*. `bytes("", ""utf8")` on the other hand, works on *Py3* but not on *Py2*.

Comment: Read the comments, it also works on 3.4.

Comment: I don't want to start an argument here. The code behaves as described in the question and I already found a solution.

Comment: I must apologize, I spoke without testing the code (only tested what I stated in my comment, and assumed that was the error). You were right, it works on *Py36* but **not** on *Py34*. Although the solution you found is better, this also works: `return bytes(self, "utf8").decode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the `__bytes__` method does not seem to be recognized on objects inherited from string by `bytes()` in python 3.4.

Changing the `__str__()` method with an explicit call to `__bytes__()` fixed the issue:

```
def __str__(self):
    """Returns the string decoded from __bytes__."""
    return self.__bytes__().decode()
```